# Convention for labeling vertices of quadrilaterals.

Tags: geometry

I am wondering if there is a convention for labeling the vertices of various quadrilaterals ABCD etc.

For example ABCD is a parallelogram. E is a point on DC extended, such that D and E are on opposite sides of BC.

Normally I put A in the top left then B in the top Right then C in the bottom left then D in the bottom right but it seems sometimes this results in incorrect construction.

Thanks!

Comment: Absent any explicit indications I would assume that the vertices of a polygon are labeled in consecutive (i.e. clockwise) order rather than in reading order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common convention is that the vertices of a polygon are listed so that adjacent vertices are connected by edges.  Thus the edges of quadrilateral $ABCD$ would be $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ and $DA$.  So if it's a parallelogram, it might look like

```
A --- B          A --- D
 \     \     or   \     \ 
  D --- C          B --- C
```

Comment: Agreed, Robert.  Usually I label counterclockwise because that is the positive orientation in the plane.

Answer (score 2):

I believe counterclockwise is the normal labeling convention - avoiding uncertainty as to what the polygon would look like.